# Pandas: dynamically calculate where churn takes place

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where every row is a company and the columns are revenue per month, like this.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data='''
Company   jan  feb  mar  apr  may  jun  jul  aug  sep  oct  nov  dec  CHURN
Dell      nan  nan  nan  600  550  620  nan  nan  300  100  200  50
Sony      740  720  780  700  250  140  20   nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
Toshiba   nan  nan  nan  nan  400  550  nan  500  nan  40   50   nan
Apple     nan  300  350  300  400  500  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
Acer      150  200  250  200  50   50   40   35   30   20   10   nan'''

df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),delimiter='\s+')
```

I need to calculate when these companies (partially) churn, if they do. My definition is as follows.

1. There have to be at least 4 consecutive months of revenue.
2. Then for 2 months, revenue has to remain below a particular point.
3. This particular point is 50% of the mean revenue of the period
   before it, starting with those 4 consecutive months.
4. The value of churn will be the month where revenue first dropped below
      that 50% point.

The result will look like this.

```
Company   jan  feb  mar  apr  may  jun  jul  aug  sep  oct  nov  dec  CHURN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dell      nan  nan  nan  600  550  620  nan  nan  300  100  200  50   
Sony      740  720  780  700  250  140  20   nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  may
Toshiba   nan  nan  nan  nan  400  550  nan  500  nan  40   50   nan  
Apple     nan  300  350  300  400  500  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  jul
Acer      150  200  250  200  50   50   40   35   30   20   10   nan  may
```

Edit:
I was going for `iloc[]` and nested for loops

```
firstrevenue=0
for row in range(0,len(df.index)-1):
    for col in range(1,12):
        if df.iloc[row,col].values > 0:
            if firstrevenue = 0:
                firstrevenue=col
```

but Roman Pekar came up with something much better. Issue resolved.

Comment: Please supply whatever attempt you have.

Comment: Can you provide the dataframe written out?

Comment: I've edited. Is this what you mean? @not_a_robot Sorry, I'm still working on it. I have a bunch of pseudocode, but I haven't gotten much further than iterrows() at this point. Working on it though.

Comment: @Duudsrednaz Is your company column taking the place of the index?

Comment: @Charles Morris  It is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can do it easily with [`pandas.Series.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html), but you can definitely do it with custom function and [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
>>> def worker(x):
...     for i in range(1, len(x) - 6):
...         d = x[i:i+4]
...         if not d.isnull().values.any():
...             if x[i+4:i+6].fillna(0).max() < d.mean()/2:
...                 return i+4
... 
>>> df.apply(worker, axis=1)
0    NaN
1    5.0
2    NaN
3    7.0
4    5.0
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew there had to be something better than just looping through everything. I'll look into `Series.rolling`. If that's quicker, I'll update.